# dropdown list not working in mobile view in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-mobile

i have 2 drop down list one is working but another is not working in mobile view. after clicking the toggle bottom in the mobile view only first dropdown only working rest of drop down list not working . why only one dropown working rest of the drop down lists are not working.

[image]

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav navbar-nav" DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu">
                     <Items>

                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Drop Down"  NavigateUrl="#">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="two" NavigateUrl="#" />
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="three" NavigateUrl="#" />
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="six" NavigateUrl="#" />
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                         <asp:MenuItem Text="Drop Down 2"  NavigateUrl="#">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="four" NavigateUrl="#" />
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="five" NavigateUrl="#" />
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="six" NavigateUrl="#" />
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                         </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Disable the default MouseOver functionality of ASP.Net Menu control.
        Sys.WebForms.Menu._elementObjectMapper.getMappedObject = function () {
            return false;
        };
        $(function () {
            //Remove the style attributes.
            $(".navbar-nav li, .navbar-nav a, .navbar-nav ul").removeAttr('style');

            //Apply the Bootstrap class to the SubMenu.
            $(".dropdown-menu").closest("li").removeClass().addClass("dropdown-toggle");

            //Apply the Bootstrap properties to the SubMenu.
            $(".dropdown-toggle").find("a").eq(0).attr("data-toggle", "dropdown").attr("aria-haspopup", "true").attr("aria-expanded", "false").append("<span class='caret'></span>");

            //Apply the Bootstrap "active" class to the selected Menu item.
            $("a.selected").closest("li").addClass("active");
            $("a.selected").closest(".dropdown-toggle").addClass("active");
        });
    </script>
    <hr />

    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 together with ASP.net menu like this (and it works)
Bootstrap CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Implement ASP.net menu like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/" alt="" width="150px" /></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="horizontal" CssClass="navbar-nav mr-auto" StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav-item" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="nav-item" StaticSubMenuIndent="16px" DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="nav-item dropdown-menu" RenderingMode="List" role="navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" >

        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="dropdown-item" HorizontalPadding="15px" Height="50px" VerticalPadding="15px" />
        </LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <LevelSelectedStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="nav-item active" Font-Underline="False" />
        </LevelSelectedStyles>
        <StaticHoverStyle Font-Underline="true" />
        <StaticSelectedStyle Font-Bold="true"   />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dropdown-item" />
</asp:Menu>
</div>
```

I'm loading several menu items from a dbase, with several drop-down menus. Maybe this example helps to solve your problem?